# Applying different color keys to one layer in AE

Tags: after-effects, greenscreen, color, chromakey

In After Effects, I have an image layer that consists a few colors. Underneath I have several other layers (textures). I want to replace each color of the image
above with one of the textures below.
Is there an easy way to apply multiple color keys to this one image - and to link each color key to a different texture layer?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make as many duplicates of the layer as there are colours. Apply the appropriate key to each copy, and place the layer you want it to reveal beneath it. On the revealed layer use a track matte, and set it to "Alpha Inverted…". This will hide the keyed layer and use its alpha channel (transparency) to reveal the layer underneath it, but only in the transparent areas.

Your layer stack will look like this, but for any areas not in any of the keys you'll also need a copy of the original layer at the *bottom* of the stack:

[image]